# Issue when creating a table with attributes non present on keyschema

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation

I'm learning DynamoDB.

I want to create a table with the following Primary Key:

- Partition key: name
- Sort key: creationDate

And with the following attributes:

- name (pk)
- address (sk)
- creationDate
- isActive

This is my TS interface (just in case it helps to describe what I want)

```
interface User {
  readonly name: string;
  readonly address: string;
  readonly creationDate: Date;
  readonly isActive: boolean;
}
```

I wrote the following template:

```yaml
Resources:
  myDynamoDBTable:
    Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
    Properties:
      AttributeDefinitions:
      - AttributeName: 'name'
        AttributeType: 'S'
      - AttributeName: 'address'
        AttributeType: 'S'
      - AttributeName: 'creationDate'
        AttributeType: 'S'
      - AttributeName: 'isActive'
        AttributeType: 'S'
      KeySchema:
      - AttributeName: 'name'
        KeyType: HASH
      - AttributeName: 'creationDate'
        KeyType: RANGE
```

When I deploy it, it fails with the following error

```
One or more parameter values were invalid: Number of attributes in KeySchema does not exactly match number of attributes defined in AttributeDefinitions
```

I google it and found several answers but I still don't understand what's going and how can I have those attributes in my table (all items are going to have those attributes).

Is there a way I can do it? If so, what am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Only attributes used as keys have to be declared upfront

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CloudFormation insists my DynamoDB creation JSON is invalid .. but I can't see how](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38142870/cloudformation-insists-my-dynamodb-creation-json-is-invalid-but-i-cant-see-h)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have `isActive` and `address` in your `AttributeDefinitions` as they are not in your `KeySchema`. You are also missing `ProvisionedThroughput`. So the correct table definition is (example):

```
Resources:
  myDynamoDBTable:
    Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
    Properties:
      AttributeDefinitions:
      - AttributeName: 'name'
        AttributeType: 'S'
      - AttributeName: 'creationDate'
        AttributeType: 'S'
      KeySchema:
      - AttributeName: 'name'
        KeyType: HASH
      - AttributeName: 'creationDate'
        KeyType: RANGE
      ProvisionedThroughput:
        ReadCapacityUnits: 1
        WriteCapacityUnits: 1
```