# DynamoDB Local - The number of attributes in key schema must match the number of attributes defined in attribute definitions

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, amazon-dynamodb

I'm running AWS DynamoDB Local docker image and I'm getting the following error when I execute `CreateTableAsync`. What's wrong with it?

> The number of attributes in key schema must match the number of attributes defined in attribute definitions.

```
version: '3.9'
name: sts-firm-service

services:
  dynamodb-local:
    container_name: dynamodb-local
    image: amazon/dynamodb-local:latest
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    networks:
      - webnet

networks:
  webnet:
    driver: bridge
```

```cs
public interface IDynamoService
{
    Task CreateTableAsync();
    Task<List<string>> GetAllTablesAsync();
}

public sealed class DynamoService : IDynamoService
{
    private readonly AmazonDynamoDBClient _client;

    public DynamoService(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(
            new BasicAWSCredentials(configuration["DynamoDB:AccessKey"], configuration["DynamoDB:SecretKey"]),
            new AmazonDynamoDBConfig
            {
                ServiceURL = "http://localhost:8000",
                AuthenticationRegion = "eu-central-1"
            });
    }

    public Task CreateTableAsync()
    {
        var bookStructureTableRequest = new CreateTableRequest
        {
            TableName = "BookStructure",
            ProvisionedThroughput = new ProvisionedThroughput
            {
                ReadCapacityUnits = 1,
                WriteCapacityUnits = 1
            },
            KeySchema = new List<KeySchemaElement>
            {
                new()
                {
                    AttributeName = "Id",
                    KeyType = KeyType.HASH
                }
            },
            AttributeDefinitions = new List<AttributeDefinition>
            {
                new()
                {
                    AttributeName = "Id",
                    AttributeType = ScalarAttributeType.S
                },
                new()
                {
                    AttributeName = "AccountExternalId",
                    AttributeType = ScalarAttributeType.S
                },
                new()
                {
                    AttributeName = "AccountLabel",
                    AttributeType = ScalarAttributeType.S
                },
                new()
                {
                    AttributeName = "BookLabel",
                    AttributeType = ScalarAttributeType.S
                },
                new()
                {
                    AttributeName = "Counterparty",
                    AttributeType = ScalarAttributeType.S
                },
                new()
                {
                    AttributeName = "LegalEntity",
                    AttributeType = ScalarAttributeType.S
                },
                new()
                {
                    AttributeName = "SecretPath",
                    AttributeType = ScalarAttributeType.S
                },
                new()
                {
                    AttributeName = "StrategyName",
                    AttributeType = ScalarAttributeType.S
                }
            }
        };

        return _client.CreateTableAsync(bookStructureTableRequest);
    }

    public async Task<List<string>> GetAllTablesAsync()
    {
        var tables = await _client.ListTablesAsync();
        return tables.TableNames;
    }
}

public class BookStructure
{
    public required string Id { get; init; }

    public required string AccountExternalId { get; init; }

    public required string AccountLabel { get; init; }

    public required string BookLabel { get; init; }

    public required string Counterparty { get; init; }

    public required string LegalEntity { get; init; }

    public required string SecretPath { get; init; }

    public required string StrategyName { get; init; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't include non key attributes in the attributes definition. Dynamodb is schemaless you don't need those -- only what will be the key

Ref: [Number of attributes in key schema must match the number of attributes defined in attribute definitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30866030/number-of-attributes-in-key-schema-must-match-the-number-of-attributes-defined-i)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so where do I put the rest of the fields?

Comment: You don't.  You can create whatever you want at runtime. Dynamo is schemaless