# DynamoDB error while creating table "Number of attributes in KeySchema does not exactly match number of attributes defined in AttributeDefinitions"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb-streams, amazon-dynamodb-index

I am using cloud formation to create DynamoDB table with following columns.
"CLAIMS_LINK_ID" (primary key), "PARTNER_NAME", "PARTNER_ID", "PARTNER_ORG_ID", "TIN","ENTITY_NAME", "STATUS", "DATA_AGREEMENT_TIMESTAMP", "RECORD_CHANGED_TIMESTAMP"

```
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
  "Resources": {
    "ClaimsLinkTable": {
      "Type": "AWS::DynamoDB::Table",
      "Properties": {
        "TableName": "CLAIMS_LINK",
        "AttributeDefinitions": [
          {
            "AttributeName": "CLAIMS_LINK_ID",
            "AttributeType": "S"
          },
          {
            "AttributeName": "PARTNER_NAME",
            "AttributeType": "S"
          },
          {
            "AttributeName": "PARTNER_ID",
            "AttributeType": "S"
          },
          {
            "AttributeName": "PARTNER_ORG_ID",
            "AttributeType": "S"
          },
          {
            "AttributeName": "TIN",
            "AttributeType": "S"
          },
          {
            "AttributeName": "ENTITY_NAME",
            "AttributeType": "S"
          },
          {
            "AttributeName": "STATUS",
            "AttributeType": "S"
          },
          {
            "AttributeName": "DATA_AGREEMENT_TIMESTAMP",
            "AttributeType": "S"
          },
          {
            "AttributeName": "RECORD_CHANGED_TIMESTAMP",
            "AttributeType": "S"
          }
        ],
        "KeySchema": [
          {
            "AttributeName": "CLAIMS_LINK_ID",
            "KeyType": "HASH"
          }
        ],
        "ProvisionedThroughput": {
          "ReadCapacityUnits": 5,
          "WriteCapacityUnits": 5
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**I am getting following error.**
Resource handler returned message: "Number of attributes in KeySchema does not exactly match number of attributes defined in AttributeDefinitions" (RequestToken: 852ea29b-08e8-fb8a-bbcf-9dad95b5c202, HandlerErrorCode: InvalidRequest)

I have attempted various solutions, but none of them proved to be  successful.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30866030/number-of-attributes-in-key-schema-must-match-the-number-of-attributes-defined-i